# Cannot Convert const char* to int in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

```
I am appending one CString value with integer but getting error as "Cannot Convert const char* to int .
int iFolderType = 0;
CString strCurrFolder = "";
                    HShareFolder = m_pTreeview->InsertItem(strCurrFolder,hChildItem);                   
                    m_pTreeview->SetItemImage(HShareFolder,2,2); 

                if(bCheck == false)
                {
                     iFolderType = eBOTH;

                }
                else
                {
                     iFolderType = eCIFS;
                }   

                strCurrFolder.Append("|");
                strCurrFolder.Append(iFolderType); //This line gives error
                m_strFolderTypeList.AddHead(strCurrFolder);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to convert it to CString or const char*. The easiest way is using CString::Format

```
CString strFolderType;
strFolderType.Format(_T("%d"), iFolderType);
strCurrFolder += strFolderType;
```